# Trouble extracting information from a financial statement while keeping the original spacing using Tesseract OCR

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, finance

I'm expected to extract information from a few hundred files of screenshots of financial statements, this is taking a very long time and I thought OCR was able to help me. With the help of the internet I was able to write a very basic python script that uses Tesseract OCR to extract the text from the file.
A picture of the pdf file used can be found here (certain things left out for security reasons): https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJDty.jpg

```
import os 
import sys 
from PIL import Image 
from pdf2image import convert_from_path 
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Convert the PDF file to an image
'''
PDF_file = "PDF\test.pdf"
pages = convert_from_path(PDF_file, 500)
image_counter = 1
for page in pages: 
    filename = "page_"+str(image_counter)+".jpg"
    page.save(filename, 'JPEG') 
    image_counter = image_counter + 1
'''
#Skipped the above part 
filename = "test pdf.jpg"

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Repair horizontal table lines 
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,1))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)

# Remove horizontal lines
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (55,2))
detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 9)

# Remove vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2,55))
detect_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 9)

#clean = cv2.rotate(image, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE) (sometimes the file is rotated)
clean = image

# Perform OCR
out_file = "out_text.txt"

f = open(out_file, "a")

#text output or hOCR output
custom_config ="config.txt"
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(clean, lang='eng',config=custom_config)
#html = str(pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(clean,config=custom_config,extension='hocr'))

f.write(data)

f.close()

cv2.imwrite('image7.png', clean)
cv2.waitKey()
```

This is working quite well but the problem is that the output files are not formatted correctly, with preserve_interword_spaces activated it isn't able to find the spacing consistently.

**Result with preserved interword spacing**

```
ASSETS                                                             Dec 2012              Dec 2013              Dec 2014 LIABILITIES                                                        Dec 2012              Dec 2013              Dec 2014 PROFIT & LOSS                                                  Dec 2012               12              Dec 2013               12              Dec 2014               12
Land and buildings                                                                        23.546                22.919 Preferred shares                                                                                                              Turnover/sales/gross revenues                                                   100%                                  100%                                  100%
Machines/equipment                                                                          298.853                             Common shares/capital                                                                                                               Costs of goods sold (-)                                              641.059            61%                 653.563            58%                 687.804            61%
Ships/aircraft                                                                                                       Paid in capital                                                                        9.960                      | GROSS TRADING PROFIT/LOSS                         412.664          39%                                42%              441.623          39%
Other fixed assets                                                                               5.962                   6.412 Revaluation reserves                                                                                                                Salaries and wages (-)                                                                  22%                                      21%                                      21%
Other reserves                                                                                                                                   Other expenses (-)                                                                             9,7%                                          13%                                         8,8%
GROSS FIXED ASSETS                                                                              358.334 Retained earnings                                                                197.859             220.589 Operating provisions (-)
Currency translation adjustment                                   (660)                                           1.360 EBITDA                                                              80.535          7,6%                 90.893          8,0%                 99.970          8,8%
Accumulated depreciation (-)                                                                                           Treasury stock (-)                                                                                                         Depreciation & amortisation (-)                                 40.519          3,8%                                  4,3%                55.368          4,9%
NET FIXED ASSETS                                             291.213               328.361               358.334 NET WORTH                                                      212.038                                        257.909 EBIT                                                                  40.016          3,8%                 42.326          3,7%                                    4,0%
Long term loans                                                                                                                Net intangibles (-)                                                                             9.038                            Other income
Investment in subsidiaries > 50 %                                                       4.417                  6.268 Loans to shareholders (-)                                                                                                   Associates (group co's/associates)                                                                         203          0,0%                    596          0,0%
Investment in associates 20 %-50 %                                                                          8.669 TANGIBLE NET WORTH                                     204.943                                     250.568 Interest expense (-)                                               5.327          0,5%                  5.822          0,5%                  5.333          0,5%
Other financial investments                                                      467                                                                 Subordinated debt                                                                                                                                            Total other financial income/exp (+/-)                                        660             0.1%                        1.499             0,1%                        1.352             0,1%
Other non-current assets                                                                                                                 Minority interest                                                               511                                                   173, OPERATING PROFIT AFTER FINANCE                         35.349           3,4%                   38.206           3,4%                   41.217           3,6%
TOTAL FIXED ASSETS                                                                  —                     373.738 OWN + ASSOC. MEANS                                                                 220.177               250.741 =Total extraordinary gains
Total extraordinary losses (-)
Group companies                                                                                                              PROFIT BEFORE TAX & MIN.INT.                             35.349          3,4%                 38.206          3,4%                 41.217          3,6%
Deferred taxes                                       9.158                                     Taxation (-)                                         12.317                        12.688       1,1%            13.517       1,2%
Net work in progress                                                                                               Other long term liabilities / provisions                        94.037                                               Minority interest (-)                                               (71)        (0,0)%                 (202)        (0,0)%                 (130)        (0,0)%
Finished goods                                                                                                  3.624 Long term debt                                                                                                            NET PROFIT/LOSS                                             23.103          2,2%                                  2,3%
Raw materials                                                   4.230                4.937                 7.724 Long term bank debt                                                                 81.924                          Dividends (% = payout ratio)                                                    24%                 4.600          18%                                  18%
Other inventory                                                                                                        LONG TERM LIABILITIES                                                          191.917              174.794 CASH FLOW SUMMARY                                                                                          2012                 2013               2014
EBITDA                                                                                                                    80.535                 90.893
TOTAL INVENTORY                                           4.230                4.937                        Group companies                                                                                               15 Annual operating lease payments (+)                                                                         21.600
Group companies                                                       6                     18                          Accounts payable                                                                                                62.951 Taxation ex non cash deferred taxes (-)
Accounts receivable                                         164.589                                              Short term bank debt                                          31.574                                                Change in other long term liabilities / provisions                                                                                     8.534
Other receivables                                                                                                      1.958 Other short term debt                                                                                                           CASH PROFIT (P)                                                                                                                               108.039              88.472
Other current assets incl. prepayments                                                                     25.932 Dividends                                                                                                                Change in asset conversion cycle (A)                                                                                                (12.118)
Marketable securities                                                                               27                            Current maturities                                                                                     0                        0 CASH PROFT AFTER ACC                                                                                                93.015                                        76.572
Cash/bank deposits                                                                   7.137               15.590 Net work in progress                                                                                                  Mandatory capital expenditure (-) (C)                                                                                                48.567
Other current liabilities                                                                                 7.421                                 OPERATIONAL CASHFLOW (PAC)                                                                                              52.696                   47.354               76.572
Accruals (tax, social security)                                                             44.653                            Mandatory dividends (-) (E)                                                                                                                       4.600               5.100
CURRENT ASSETS                                          221.606                                     239.307 CURRENT LIABILITIES                                      133.140                                                 Interest expense and Capitalised interest (-) (D)                                                                                                           5.333
Current Maturities (-) (t-1) (D)                                                                                                                     0                    0
TOTAL ASSETS                                                                    562.245                        TOTAL LIABILITIES                                                               562.245              613.045 Annual operating lease payments (-) (D)                                                                                             21.300
STATISTICS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     FINANCING CHARGES (ED)                                                                                   32.427               31.722             10.433
Gross capital expenditure                                                                102.562                           Total debt                                                                                   121.520               135.482 OPERATIONAL CASHFLOW AFTER FINANCING CHARGES                                                   20.269                                      66.139
Mandatory capital expenditure                                 40.319                                                Contingent liabilities                                           145.416                                                 Non oper. items (min.int. oth inc, other inc/exp, extra +/-,assoc)                                                  731                 1.904              2.078
Number of employees                                             4.955                                                  Annual operating lease payments                                                                                          Change in fixed assets & intangible assets in addition to mandatory CAPEX (-)                                                      42.312             83.995
Capitalised interest                                                                                                          Non-cash deferred taxes                                                                                                     Change in other current assets & liabilities                                                                                                   8.824               5.418
Gross work in progress                                                                                                                                                                                                                          FUNDS BEFORE EXTERNAL FINANCING                                                                    (8.188)                                  (10.360)
RATIOS                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Change in net worth (excl. retained earnings)                                                                                                         6.137
Current ratio                                                        a                  1,46                      | Operational cashflow over Financing Charges                  1,63                                                Change in long term liabilities                                                                                                                           (1.003)
Quick ratio                                                                                                    1,22 Operational cashflow over Debt Charges                                                                            Change in long term debt (incl. bank)
Days inventory                                                                                                     ' Cash profit over Financing Charges                                                                          8,48 Change in short term debt (incl. bank) & current maturities                                                 (33.548)
Days receivable                                                                         54,73                         Net Worth / Adjustm. total assets                                                                                      Adjustments to retained earnings                                                                                                                                0
Days payable                                                                        33,13                      ' Tangible net worth / Total assets                                                                                   CHANGE IN CASH, BANKS & MARKET. SECURITIES                                                                         (15.194)
Total debt / EBITDA                                                                                       ' Own+tassoc. means / Total assets                                                0,39                        Remarks
Senior debt / EBITDA                                                                                                 Gearing (total debt / TNW)                                                              0,55
Operating margin                                                                                                   0,04 Interest cover ratio
Return on capital employed
Turnover growth                                                                  0,00
```

**Results without spacing**

```
ASSETS Dec 2012 Dec 2013 Dec 2014 LIABILITIES Dec 2012 Dec 2013 Dec 2014 PROFIT & LOSS Dec 2012 12 Dec 2013 12 Dec 2014 12
Land and buildings 23.546 22.919 Preferred shares Turnover/sales/gross revenues 100% 100% 100%
Machines/equipment 298.853 Common shares/capital Costs of goods sold (-) 641.059 61% 653.563 58% 687.804 61%
Ships/aircraft Paid in capital 9.960 | GROSS TRADING PROFIT/LOSS 412.664 39% 42% 441.623 39%
Other fixed assets 5.962 6.412 Revaluation reserves Salaries and wages (-) 22% 21% 21%
Other reserves Other expenses (-) 9,7% 13% 8,8%
GROSS FIXED ASSETS 358.334 Retained earnings 197.859 220.589 Operating provisions (-)
Currency translation adjustment (660) 1.360 EBITDA 80.535 7,6% 90.893 8,0% 99.970 8,8%
Accumulated depreciation (-) Treasury stock (-) Depreciation & amortisation (-) 40.519 3,8% 4,3% 55.368 4,9%
NET FIXED ASSETS 291.213 328.361 358.334 NET WORTH 212.038 257.909 EBIT 40.016 3,8% 42.326 3,7% 4,0%
Long term loans Net intangibles (-) 9.038 Other income
Investment in subsidiaries > 50 % 4.417 6.268 Loans to shareholders (-) Associates (group co's/associates) 203 0,0% 596 0,0%
Investment in associates 20 %-50 % 8.669 TANGIBLE NET WORTH 204.943 250.568 Interest expense (-) 5.327 0,5% 5.822 0,5% 5.333 0,5%
Other financial investments 467 Subordinated debt Total other financial income/exp (+/-) 660 0.1% 1.499 0,1% 1.352 0,1%
Other non-current assets Minority interest 511 173, OPERATING PROFIT AFTER FINANCE 35.349 3,4% 38.206 3,4% 41.217 3,6%
TOTAL FIXED ASSETS — 373.738 OWN + ASSOC. MEANS 220.177 250.741 =Total extraordinary gains
Total extraordinary losses (-)
Group companies PROFIT BEFORE TAX & MIN.INT. 35.349 3,4% 38.206 3,4% 41.217 3,6%
Deferred taxes 9.158 Taxation (-) 12.317 12.688 1,1% 13.517 1,2%
Net work in progress Other long term liabilities / provisions 94.037 Minority interest (-) (71) (0,0)% (202) (0,0)% (130) (0,0)%
Finished goods 3.624 Long term debt NET PROFIT/LOSS 23.103 2,2% 2,3%
Raw materials 4.230 4.937 7.724 Long term bank debt 81.924 Dividends (% = payout ratio) 24% 4.600 18% 18%
Other inventory LONG TERM LIABILITIES 191.917 174.794 CASH FLOW SUMMARY 2012 2013 2014
EBITDA 80.535 90.893
TOTAL INVENTORY 4.230 4.937 Group companies 15 Annual operating lease payments (+) 21.600
Group companies 6 18 Accounts payable 62.951 Taxation ex non cash deferred taxes (-)
Accounts receivable 164.589 Short term bank debt 31.574 Change in other long term liabilities / provisions 8.534
Other receivables 1.958 Other short term debt CASH PROFIT (P) 108.039 88.472
Other current assets incl. prepayments 25.932 Dividends Change in asset conversion cycle (A) (12.118)
Marketable securities 27 Current maturities 0 0 CASH PROFT AFTER ACC 93.015 76.572
Cash/bank deposits 7.137 15.590 Net work in progress Mandatory capital expenditure (-) (C) 48.567
Other current liabilities 7.421 OPERATIONAL CASHFLOW (PAC) 52.696 47.354 76.572
Accruals (tax, social security) 44.653 Mandatory dividends (-) (E) 4.600 5.100
CURRENT ASSETS 221.606 239.307 CURRENT LIABILITIES 133.140 Interest expense and Capitalised interest (-) (D) 5.333
Current Maturities (-) (t-1) (D) 0 0
TOTAL ASSETS 562.245 TOTAL LIABILITIES 562.245 613.045 Annual operating lease payments (-) (D) 21.300
STATISTICS FINANCING CHARGES (ED) 32.427 31.722 10.433
Gross capital expenditure 102.562 Total debt 121.520 135.482 OPERATIONAL CASHFLOW AFTER FINANCING CHARGES 20.269 66.139
Mandatory capital expenditure 40.319 Contingent liabilities 145.416 Non oper. items (min.int. oth inc, other inc/exp, extra +/-,assoc) 731 1.904 2.078
Number of employees 4.955 Annual operating lease payments Change in fixed assets & intangible assets in addition to mandatory CAPEX (-) 42.312 83.995
Capitalised interest Non-cash deferred taxes Change in other current assets & liabilities 8.824 5.418
Gross work in progress FUNDS BEFORE EXTERNAL FINANCING (8.188) (10.360)
RATIOS Change in net worth (excl. retained earnings) 6.137
Current ratio a 1,46 | Operational cashflow over Financing Charges 1,63 Change in long term liabilities (1.003)
Quick ratio 1,22 Operational cashflow over Debt Charges Change in long term debt (incl. bank)
Days inventory ' Cash profit over Financing Charges 8,48 Change in short term debt (incl. bank) & current maturities (33.548)
Days receivable 54,73 Net Worth / Adjustm. total assets Adjustments to retained earnings 0
Days payable 33,13 ' Tangible net worth / Total assets CHANGE IN CASH, BANKS & MARKET. SECURITIES (15.194)
Total debt / EBITDA ' Own+tassoc. means / Total assets 0,39 Remarks
Senior debt / EBITDA Gearing (total debt / TNW) 0,55
Operating margin 0,04 Interest cover ratio
Return on capital employed
Turnover growth 0,00
```

I also tried the hOCR, which transforms it into coordinates which is then suitable to be parsed with HTML. The results weren't promising either.

**HTML**
The file is too long. When parsed it cant find the proper table.

My goal is to have it give a clean text files in which the columns are spaced nicely and then be able to transform it into an excel file. Where all the lines line up correctly so I am able to process a large amount of files and transfer the information to one excel file. All help is welcome since I am just an intern an not very knowledgeable about Python.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You first step should be to crop out single tables and ocr table by table.

Comment: do i do this by detecting the vertical lines and horizontal lines through the hough method?

Comment: The only problem i expect is that the fields containing the numbers are not separated by lines, id have to find another solution for that

Comment: ***"numbers are not separated by lines"***: The linked answer claim to do so. Consider to close this question as duplicate.